# Toggle CSS Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background, slidetoggle

I am using this code to show/hide content:

```
$(function(){
  $('#slider').css('display','');

  $('#hideslider').click(function(){
    $('#slider').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).toggleClass('slideSign');
    return false;
  });
});
```

When `#hideslider` is clicked it shows/hides the content in `#slider`. `#hideslider` is using an up arrow as a background image in the css. Is there a way to change this background image when `#slider` is not displaying to a down arrow. For example, if `#slider` display is `'none'` then display a different background image in `#hideslider`. Thanks for help.

Comment: Learn to format code. :)

Comment: what does `slideSign` class do here??

Comment: Can you show a simple [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make new CSS definitions for the class that will use a down arrow.

```
.down-arrow{
    background:url('/path/to/my/downarrow.ext') other-properties;
}
```

Then access the callback within the slideToggle function to evaluate the display state of the element.

```
$('#slider').slideToggle('slow', function(){
    //here we have the callback, the slide has finished, and now we can evaluate
    if($(this).css('display') == 'none'){
        //We know that we should add the class..
        $('#hideslide').addClass('down-arrow');
    }else{
        $('#hideslide').removeClass('down-arrow');
    }
});
```